# Problemas com mouseenter() e mouseleave()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando passo o mouse no primeiro link com a class show_post ele exibe a div correta que tem de exibir, mas quando passo o mouse no segundo link o script abre as 2 divs e não somente a solicitada.

Segue o fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pabloworks/m4q6B/

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn-abs prev-new hide show_post" data-id="1">&#9668;</a>

        <div class="post-prev content-show" id="1">
            <a href="#">
             <span>titulo 01</span>
            </a>
        </div>


<a href="#" class="btn-abs next-new hide show_post" data-id="2"><span>&#9658;</span></a>

        <div class="post-next content-show" id="2"> 
            <a href="#">
             <span>titulo 02</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
$(".post-prev, .post-next").hide();
    var id;

    $('.show_post').mouseenter(function(){
   id = '.post-prev, .post-next #'+$(this).data("id");

   console.log(id); //verificando o id de quem disparou o evento

   $(id).stop().fadeIn('fast');
    })

    .mouseleave(function(){
   $(id).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: O código no jsfiddle está diferente do código colocado aqui

Comment: faltou uma class, eu já alterei lá ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hum... Se a `div`que deve aparecer / desaparecer é sempre o próximo elemento após o link, utilize a função [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('.show_post').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).next().stop().fadeIn('fast');
})

$('.show_post').mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).next().stop().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Com isso você não vai mais precisar dos `ids`, `data-id`, etc.

Comment: Que trapalhada que eu fiz! Primeiro uma resposta errada, depois outra duplicada... Chega, +1 pra você.

Comment: Eu ia postar, vi sua resposta, cancelei a minha e votei a sua. Vi que você deletou, digitei a resposta pela segunda vez e postei. Estamos sofrendo de Livelock :).

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou http://jsfiddle.net/pabloworks/m4q6B/ agora vou resolver um probleminha de css que não me permite clicar no conteúdo exibido =D